# Is this the correct AC analysis of the following circuit?

Tags: ac, common-emitter

If I have the following circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4xtqr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is this AC analysis correct? I am not sure if I should add the R4 resistor in series with the re resistor or not?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMWkFr.png)</sup>

Comment: @Diana R5 is bypassed for AC purposes but you do need R4. (And I'm not taking your model as otherwise acceptable, just yet.)

Comment: R1//R2 missing correct values and R3 is missing which attenuates input by 10% or so  then multiplies output Rc/Re=50 so net gain is ~50

Comment: The designators have changed so my comment isn't right, anymore. Oh, well.

Comment: Re, if it's the internal emitter resistance, should be in series with R3.